# Need to access SQL using "mysql root -p"

Tags: mysql, cmd, path, passwords, root

Hey guys: I have one question access mysql using command line. I have no problem to access mysql based on this commend line "mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password="mypassword""; however, I have issue access mysql using the conventional way: "mysql root -p". I've tried many times to change root password. But I still only can access mysql using this commend line "mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password="mypassword"". Any comments are welcoming!

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES). However, if I use commend line mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password="mypassword; I got no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect command as conventional way.

The error you mentioned in comment indicates that MySQL username is "ODBC" & you are not passing proper MySQL user in the command line. That is happening because you are using "mysql root -p".

Correct command is "mysql -u root -p". You missed the "-u " part.